# Do I need RDS CALs for the users that come with Windows Server 2012 R2 Foundation?

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, remote-desktop, rds, remoteapp

I bought a server hardware with a Windows Server 2012 R2 Foundation license. That license comes with 15 users, which is sufficient for my needs. I'd like to use the server for RemoteApps. I configured everything and it works fine, but RD Licensing Diagnostics says I have no licenses. On the other hand, RD Licensing Manager reports I have an unlimited number of device TS-CALs of Windows 2000 Server type.

Do I need to buy additional device or user CALs if I want to stay below the 15 user limit?

Comment: Have you... *activated* RDS?

Comment: Yes I have. I activated the RD Licensing Server with Microsoft. Everything works, but since I am in this 120 days grace period, I don't know how long.

Comment: You need to purchase RDS CAL's (not to exceed 15). - https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj679892(v=ws.11).aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to purchase RDS CAL's (not to exceed 15).

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj679892%28v=ws.11%29.aspx